# Asignación de variables de fecha planas en un case

Tags: sql-server, variables

Estoy empezando a programar en sql server y mi intención es de la variable @AAAA tengo el dato año y lo quiero comparar con el campo falta decimal (8,0) que tiene fecha plana aaaammdd  y quiero que el sql le asigne a la variable @fechaalta el valor 12 en el caso que @AAAA sea mayor o igual. En el caso que @AAAA es menor que a la constante 13 le reste los dos numeros de la posición 5 (mes).
Esta sentencia tiene desde errores de sintaxis, hasta de lógica.

```
Declare @AAAA decimal (4,0);
Declare @Fechaalta decimal (8,0);


SELECT CAST(
            CASE 
                 WHEN @AAAA > LEFT(falta,4)
                    then set @Fechaalta = 12
               
             ELSE set (@Fechaalta = 13 - (SUBSTRING (falta. 5,2))                   

            END )

from [base].[dbo].[tabla]
```

Comment: Si tienes multiples filas en la `tabla`, ¿Qué valor esperas que quede en las variables al terminar la ejecución de la consulta?. Creo que convendría que edites tu pregunta y le añadas algunos datos de ejemplo que tendrías en la tabla (dos o tres filas) y cual es el resultado esperado luego de ejecutar el código. De esta manera quedará más claro para escribir una respuesta.

Answer (score 1):

Uno de las primeras cosas que tienes que tener en cuenta, es que asignar un valor a una variable que solo puede contener 1, desde una tabla que puede contener varios, implica al menos pérdida de información. Si tienes 2 filas en tabla, ¿Cuál va a ser la que alimenta a la variable @fechaAlta?

En TSQL (al igual que en el resto de lenguajes de bases de datos) no existe el concepto orden. Por tanto no se puede predecir si se asignaría el valor de la fila "1" o "2".

```
CREATE TABLE TABLA (Falta decimal(8,0));
GO

INSERT INTO 
TABLA (Falta)
VALUES
(20100701),
(20200401);
GO
```

De este ejemplo donde tengo dos filas, puedo evaluar para cada fila el valor de una variable.

```
Declare @AAAA decimal(4, 0);

Declare @FECHAALTA decimal(8, 0);

-- Para asignar valores, podemos utilizar Set o Select

SET @AAAA = 2020;
-- ES LO MISMO QUE

SELECT @AAAA = 2015;

SELECT CAST(LEFT(cast(falta as varchar(8)), 4) AS DECIMAL(4, 0)) as Año
     , @AAAA as [Parametro AAAA]
     , FALTA as [Valor columna]
     , CASE
            WHEN @AAAA > CAST(LEFT(CAST(falta as varchar(8)), 4) AS DECIMAL(4, 0)) then 12
            ELSE 13 - SUBSTRING(CAST(falta as varchar(8)), 5, 2)
       END as [Resultado Expresion]
       from tabla;
```

[image: Resultado]

Esto como se ve en la imagen, está bien, pero si yo asigno Resultado Expresión a la variable @FechaAlta, no puedo asegurar que va a contener un 12 o un 9, salvo que utilizase order by.

Suponiendo que solo tuvieses una fila.

```
Declare @AAAA decimal(4, 0);
Declare @FECHAALTA decimal(2); -- si solo voy a contener un número de dos dígitos

SELECT @AAAA = 2015;

SELECT @FECHAALTA = -- Asigno a la variable el valor del case
       (CASE
            WHEN @AAAA > CAST(LEFT(CAST(falta as varchar(8)), 4) AS DECIMAL(4, 0)) then 12
            ELSE 13 - SUBSTRING(CAST(falta as varchar(8)), 5, 2)
       END ) 
       from tabla;

-- Visualizo el resultado asignado a la variable.
SELECT @FECHAALTA AS Resultado

Resultado
---------------------------------------
9

(1 fila afectada)
```

Los problemas que te puede presentar son las conversiones de tipo.

Si voy a utilizar la función left y esta devuelve la parte izquierda de una cadena de caracteres con el número de caracteres especificado. Tengo que convertir a cadenas de caracteres el tipo de dato. Para muchas de ellas, existe lo que se llama conversión implícita, donde el motor lo realiza de un modo transparente, pero siempre es mucho mejor hacerlo de una manera explicita en la query.

[Left](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/functions/left-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

[SubString](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/functions/substring-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)